# Creating a Folder that pulls in links to files in multiple other folders

Tags: .net, winapi

I may be a little out of my depth, but I figure that this should be possible, I was wondering if there was a way to create a folder that looks through a number of other folders and creates links to certain files within those folders. Essentially, the idea is that One department has a lot of files scattered throughout a lot of folders, and another department needs access to those files, but does not want to have to navigate through the unfamiliar, relatively complicated, directory, so I want to create a single folder that creates shortcuts to everything they need, and that updates the shortcuts that it contains as new files are added.

Should I be using the Win32 API or the .NET framework? Or are neither of these appropriate for what I'm attempting? Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: A saved search in Windows 7 might be all you need.  Just do a search for the files you want in Explorer and click "Save search".  When you reopen the saved search you get fresh results.  The target folders need to be indexed for this to perform adequately.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I hadn't thought about that. I'll play around with it, but I don't think it will offer the flexibility I am looking for. I haven't been given a full list of files that I will need to pull in, but I know there will be situations where a folder contains subfolders called "2009", "2010", "2011", "2012", etc., and I want the folder to automatically pull in the files from the current year without having to update the year in the saved search manually when we hit 2013.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [Hard Link/Junction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365006.aspx) or a [Symbolic Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365680.aspx) in your folder that point to a file in another folder.